# Intellisense popup for template code (Visual Studio 2019)

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2019

When you define a template, VS 2019 shows a floating pop with the text `<T> Provide sample template arguments for Intellisense`. You can supply a template type like `int`, but is there a way to get this floating box to disappear without turning Intellisense off completely?

Example:

```
template <typename T> // popup box appears here after a few seconds, see image
struct POINT {
    T x, y;
}
```

[image: Example showing the popup box]

Answer (score 51, accepted):

This is Visual Studio's [template intellisense](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/cppblog/template-intellisense/). If you want its features, then you should click the pencil icon on the right side of the dialog, and provide a sample type for the template. If you don't want the template intellisense features, then you can turn it off in `Tools > Options > Text Editor > C/C++ > Advanced > IntelliSense > Enable Template IntelliSense`.

Comment: Awesome, that's it!

Comment: why this annoying feature is turned on by default in a first place???

Comment: This turns off the entire feature, not just the popup.

Comment: Thank you, this is one of the more annoying UI features in newer VS. It's nice to be able to specialize templates, but when the cost is that you have to click twice (and be very careful where you click) in the code editor to _avoid_ getting a popup, someone has seriously failed at their task of UI testing :P

Comment: Very helpful, thanks, and not findable by search box in settings. Also, "Auto Quick Info" = False is a lifesaver with the instant hover popups in VS2022

Comment: Awesome! Really helped! Tried to understand the use of this feature on the official website of VS, but no use. It's a terrible feature because my code was not getting compiled, for no reason. Complete waste of time. Thanks @Aplet123!

Comment: Probably because it _is_ helpful for troubleshooting template code, @def, since it lets IntelliSense instantiate the template with a default set of parameters, without affecting the code itself.  Basically, it lets you include default parameters that only IntelliSense (and not actual code) can see, or feed potentially problematic parameters into the IDE to help locate errors within the code.  The only problem is that it isn't always collapsed by default; it should _always_ start as a little `<T>` to the right of the template, and only expand if actually clicked on.

Comment: Template IntelliSense is just for IntelliSense, @Shreekant, it doesn't actually affect compilation.  All it does is let you give IntelliSense a set of sample template parameters, so it can use them to examine the template.  It's purely an IDE helper and nothing else, basically.

Comment: @JustinTime-ReinstateMonica Thanks for a very concise and useful comment. I understand the purpose must be just to provide an interllisense, which is of course a great feature of VS. And, though it might sound a little weird, in my case it stopped giving a build error, just after turning off the setting.
Honestly, I am not sure about the technical reason, why it happened.

Comment: Template IntelliSense affecting a build error like that definitely is weird, @Shreekant, that's for certain; it really isn't _supposed_ to affect anything other than the... I believe it was the IntelliSense database (I'm not too sure of the exact internal mechanics myself, alas).  If you can narrow it down any more than that, it might be worth reporting on https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/VisualStudio , so they can hopefully fix it.